# If I have Scala plugin installed in intellij, can i acces it globally?

Tags: windows, scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

I'm just getting started with scala, and im using intellij.

I have just installed the plugin with the tool in intellij, and this now works.

But i would like to also maybe run Scala from cmd. Is it necessary for me to download Scala via the browser also? or could I just add scala in intellij to enviorment variables, and have it working?

Comment: The Scala plugin checks your code, highlights it, etc. It is not a replacement for the Scala compiler, which generates .class files from your code. So yes, you will have to download Scala. You could also download SBT and use it to build Scala projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can.

Intellij IDEA can install scala plugin with scala sdk and sbt.
If you have sbt somewhere, you can find and run it.

I was able to find my installation by opening the existing sbt project, then go to `Project structure ->  Modules -> sbt` there would be the path.

I find myself path like this - `jar:file:/C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/193.6015.39.plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar`

You can start sbt by `java -jar sbt-launch.jar`.